# PHP Sending Automated Mail That Doesn't Goto The SPAM Folder?

Tags: php, email

I've always been a little troubled when it comes to sending mail through PHP functions.
But it hasn't really been a problem until my latest project.

I'm looking for the absolute best way of sending mail through PHP and not having it end up in the SPAM folder :/

I'm aware that it won't probably work 100% of the time,
I'm just looking for the best option.

Thanks :)

Comment: The best option is to send it manually, and not advertise stuff.

Comment: Check your: Reverse DNS, SPF, DKIM, Hashcash, .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to avoid a system generated e-mail going into spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800898/php-how-to-avoid-a-system-generated-e-mail-going-into-spam)

Comment: It's not for Spamming purposes, it's for "Your account is active/Thank you e-mail". That kind of thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number one reason mail usually ends up in the SPAM folder (when the content isn't actually spammy) is that the `From:` header isn't set or is set to a non-existant email address. If the header is empty the message will appear to come from something like `webmaster@localdomain`.

In the `mail()` call (refer to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) be sure to populate the `$additional_headers` field like:

```
mail('to@example.com', 'Subject', 'Body text...', 
             'From: me@realaddress.com');
```

That should get you past almost all spam filters -- assuming you're not actually sending out spammy content! :)

Comment: No problem -- be sure to mark the answer as accepted (or someone else's answer if you like it better) to help people searching for this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Use a libary like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and make sure to fill out all email header fields correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching, try reading codinghorror's summary on making sure, in the most possible way, that emails are not flagged as spam.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html