# send automated mail that wont go into spam

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing code that generates a random_password when a user has forgotten there password and sends it there email address. the code works fine except it goes into spam, my question is, are there any measures I can take that will get the message to go into inbox, or do you need to be registered as a genuine company company to have automated emails certified. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an [SPF record](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786) for your domain ?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question.

Comment: Sometimes it is the length of your message. You could always say please add [address] to your address book, or check your spam folder if you don't get the message in xx minutes.

Comment: Thanks, that link was very interesting I will research it. I appreciate that.

Comment: that's a good idea, thanks Ryan B

Comment: Can you put the headers of the spam reason explanation of the mail? Something like: X-Spam-Status: LOW ; 43
X-Spam-Level: xxxx+++
X-Spam-Report: HTML_MESSAGE,MSGID_MULTIPLE_AT,SHORT_HELO_AND_INLINE_IMAGE,SUBJ_ALL_CAPS

Answer (score 2):

You can't be 100% certain of staying out of all SPAM filters; you can only take steps to make your message look as non-SPAMmy as possible. A few ideas:

- Utilize [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) & [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)
- [Sign your messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (will require that you have a valid certificate that isn't self-signed)
- Use a valid `From:` address (and the rest of the header data too, while you're at it)
- Properly include both text/plain and HTML-formatted version of your message
- Avoid using SPAM-like trigger phrases ([SpamAssassin's default rules](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_3_x.html) are a good place to look).
- Make sure your SMTP servers & domain aren't on any [DNS blacklists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)

See also [this earlier discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728791/php-sending-automated-mail-that-doesnt-goto-the-spam-folder?rq=1)